# Eclipse claims Commons-Codec methods don't exist

Tags: java, eclipse, apache-commons-codec

I'm working on validating the signed_request parameter from the Facebook API, following [these guidelines](http://www.sergiy.ca/how-to-implement-facebook-oauth-2.0-app-authorization-process-in-java/), but I'm running into issues calling some of the methods of the Base64 class from Commons Codec. I added the commons-codec 1.6 library to my project ([image: picture of my referenced libraries]), but Eclipse is showing

[image: Constructor with red underline]

and saying

[image: Error message (Constructor Base64(boolean) is undefined)]

which is odd, since [this says otherwise](http://commons.apache.org/codec/api-release/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html#Base64(boolean)).

I verified the md5 of the download, so that's not the issue.

Any bright ideas?

Comment: Are you importing the correct Base64 class?

Comment: import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

Comment: Make sure the "Link with Editor" icon button at the top of the package explorer is pressed, and the ctrl-click on the Base64 type in your editor. Then check if the selected class file in the package editor is the class inside the commons-codec-1.6.jar, or if it's a class in another jar.

Comment: Is there a reason why you're creating a new instance of the class?  The `decodeBase64()` method is static.

Comment: @Michael: URL-safe decoding, as per http://www.sergiy.ca/how-to-implement-facebook-oauth-2.0-app-authorization-process-in-java/ . I've been having issues with making the process work, so I'm trying to follow the tutorial as identically as possible.

Comment: @JBNizet: Ah, there we go. Looks like GWT includes a version of commons codec as well. How do I make it refer to the library that I included instead, though?

Comment: @JBNizet Figured it out, just needed to bump up commons codec in the build order.

Comment: @JBNizet Can you quickly write an answer to your question?  That way, it makes it easier for others to see the solution.

Comment: @Michael: I just did it.

Comment: @JBNizet Oh ok thanks.  You have to mark it as the answer too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you have another version of commons-codes classes in your classpath, before the commons-codec jar you installed.

Make sure the "Link with Editor" icon button at the top of the package explorer is pressed, and then ctrl-click on the Base64 type in your editor. Then check if the selected class file in the package editor is the class inside the commons-codec-1.6.jar, or if it's a class in another jar.

Comment: for people who might get difficulties in finding "Link with Editor" icon, check this link for screen shot http://www.mainelydesign.com/blog/view/best-eclipse-feature-link-with-editor

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. It got resolved after I moved the codec jar in the build order. But I couldn't able to build the GWT project. It shows the following error

String key = new String(Base64.decodeBase64("xxxx"));

error: method decodeBase64 in class Base64 cannot be applied to given types;
"actual argument String cannot be converted to byte[] by method invocation conversion".

The JRE still reads the codec package from GWT package. How to resolve this?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.